# Relacionar dos tablas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos

¿Puedo relacionar dos columnas a una misma tabla? por ejemplo

Tengo dos columnas en una tabla RADICADOS (delegate_id) y (createBy_id) y quiero relacionar estas dos al "ID" de la tabla USERS, que por ejemplo:

Cuando utilice `$radicado->delegate_id->name` (me aparezca el nombre JUAN)
y cuando utilice `$radicado->createBy_id->name` (me aparezca el nombre de MAURICIO)

Si es posible por favor, y me digan como puedo hacerlo y que tipos de relaciones utilziar

Comment: Sí es posible, pero debes adelantar lo que más puedas del trabajo, mostrarnos tus avances, y nosotros te solucionamos las partes donde tengas problemas.

Comment: Listo amigo, estoy trabajando en eso, estoy construyendo un sistema bastante grande y es confortable tener el apoyo de todos ustedes, apenas tenga avances actualizaré el post

Answer (score 1):

Si claro! te recomiendo leer en la documentacion Eloquent ORM de laravel, en donde aparece todo bien detallado ([AQUÍ](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one))

voy a suponer que los 2 modelos son los siguientes: Radicado y User

En el modelo User deberías apuntar estos 2 atributos al modelo Radicado. Asumiendo que son 1:1 quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
....

public function radicadoDelegate()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Radicado', 'delegate_id');
}

public function radicadoCreateBy()
{
return $this->hasOne('App\Radicado', 'createBy_id');
}
```

Fíjate que que al método HasOne le estoy pasando 2 parámetros, el primero es el modelo al cual quiero llegar y el segundo es la clave foranea de ese modelo.

Por otra parte, el modelo Radicado quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
....

public function delegateId()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'delegate_id');
}

public function createById()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'createBy_id');
}
```

(Te recomiendo escribir los métodos de tu modelo de esa forma para no confundir los atributos con los métodos cuando los estés llamando desde tu instancia).

Ejemplo:

```
$radicado = Radicado::find(1);

$radicado->delegateId->name;
$radicado->createById->name;
```

Me avisas como te va, saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu colaboración amigo !! efectivamente me ayudó mucho y funciono, y si, tengo todo así como lo has planteado

Answer (score 0):

Esto no funciona por arte de magia

```
$radicado->delegate_id->name
$radicado->createBy_id->name
```

tienes que ir a tu modelo de radiacion y crear una relación hasOne, como por ejemplo

```
public function creador()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'createBy_id');
    }
```

y luego ya la podras usar

```
$radicado->creador->name
```

Comment: Gracias por ti colaboración amigo, también me fue muy útil esta ayuda, las dos respuestas me funcionaron muy bien

Comment: @AndresMestra la mejor forma de agradecer es marcar la respuesta que te solucionó el problema como aceptada